# Is SSL really safe?

Tags: android, ssl

I have an android application that implements SSL, I thought it was safe to transmit private data, but after reading this I'm not sure

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2210832716300722

SSL is good security or should it also encrypt (AES, RSA ...) the data that is sent to the server?

Comment: I assume you are referring to TLS (v1.2), not SSL. SSL is broken by design.

Comment: TLS is "good security" ... as long as it is used properly. What the article shows is the many libraries/applications errors/misuses of it in order to go around difficulties (certificates verification) or just silence all error messages, leaving the user  in the blind. This is another good article on the same kind of issues (showing the problem is not just in Android, and certainly not just in HTTPS): https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL is designed to be secure on all devices as it uses end-to-end public key encryption to secure the data packets.

However, in your article they talk about man-in-the-middle attacks where the data is send via another server (often non-secure) this is a breach in the rules of SSL and secure online transactions.

I would always look for the "Secure" next to the https:// address and "Lock" icon in the browser - you can also view the certificate and if it matches the website you are on it should be good to go.

Remember nothing is 100% safe

Hope that helps @Apyc

Comment: "view the certificate and if it matches the website you are on it should be good to go" only if you control the list of CAs in your truststore otherwise you are blindly giving your trust to hundreds of remote organizations, including governments.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends of the data that you are sending and how you are receiveng them on server side.
It is no 100% secure encryption, it only depends of how actual are the data at the moment of crack. 
And Don't forget that each step of encryption is slowing down the connection and data transmitting between server and client.

Comment: *Don't forget that each step of encryption is slowing down the connection*  this is often negligible today... you may worry more on the cost in CPU hence in battery life.

Comment: Using more layers of encryption means more CPU usage, especially for phones/tablets it may be considerable. This is what i meant. Is not about the storage.

Comment: There are components optimized to offload all crypto works, so they are optimized for that and run fast enough. But they have to run, hence consume energy. This is the major problem to bring decent security to IoT devices that are seldom powered-on or for short times (in order to save on battery) and have very narry bandwitdh to communicate.